# Java Jersey Client API

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am new to Java Jersey Client API and would like to login to the server, such as:

> ```
> POST http:/xxxx.net/auth/login
>
> Content-Type: application/json
> {"login": "xxxxx", "password": "XXXXX"}
> ```

Could you show me an example for such a Java Jersey client API code?

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462955/authentication-in-jersey

Comment: Did you try googling it? http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: Yes, but I don't get how to add the login and password to the WebResource.

Comment: It totally depends on how you're actually sending the data in the request. You can see the parameters that Jersey can consume here: http://technopaper.blogspot.com/2009/03/jersey-annotations-explained.html

Answer (score 1):

```
// create a Jersey client
Client client = Client.create();

// create the JSON as a Map 
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put("login", "xxxxx");
data.put("password", "xxxxx");

// post to the resource with APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE and it will be converted to JSON for you
client.resource("http://xxxx.net/auth/login")
      .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
      .post(data);
```